# Can't able to login in to the wordpress admin dashboard..?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, admin

Just now I have installed wordpress 4.2 for my blog. It's not multi site wordpress. If I am trying to login in to dashboard using UN & PW nothing happens.. Page loads and displays login page again.. Nothing happens other than that. If I use wrong credentials error message also not getting displayed..

Note: I installed wordpress in a directory. Already I have installed another wordpress in same domain using different directory name. Is this causing problem???

Comment: Please be specific about your problem, if possible please provide what you've done so far, and give us your error messages if it show you an error. :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use two or more WordPress on same domain and directories, because for every single WordPress site u must also have a unique database defined for it.
I think your database conflict the two WordPress site in the same domain.